# ListView with custom CursorAdapter doesn't work well

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

In a part of my android application I have a `ListView` that shows list of entries in a table. When user tap on a `ListView` item a new `Intent` for this item is shown.

In the new intent user can do some operations on this entry as *reading*, *editing*, *favoriting* (and *unfavoriting* when item is already favorited). In the detail intent I change the "marked" column of the entry in its table to **1** when it is **favorited** and to **0** when **unfavorited**.

It works fine. But the problem is in my master `ListView`. I set a custom `CursorAdapter` for my `ListView`. I wanted to add `ImageView` that indicates weather the entry is *favorited* or not. In the layout file of my `ListView` item I added an `ImageView` for this and set its `visibility` to `GONE`.

I want to detect favorited item and set its star `ImageView` `visibility` to `VISIBLE`. Then I ran the application in my device. As usual none of the entries is favorited. Then tapped on the first item in the `ListView` and details page for this item opened. I *favorited* it and went back to the list.

Ok, now there is a star icon on the fist item, but not only on this but also some other items. The detail page for these wrong starred items says that it is not *favorited*. So the problem is not with my database operations. Also I checked cursor that shows marked items and its `.getCount()` also said that only **1** item *favorited*. I can't find where there is the problem. I wrote my simplified source code for custom `CursorAdapter` bellow:

```
public class HereIsMyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public HereIsMyAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, true);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView txtTestText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTestText);
        ImageView imgMark = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgMark);

        txtSureAz.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("azname")));

        boolean isMarked = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("marked")) == 1 ? true : false;

        if (isMarked) {
            imgMark.setVisibility(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
        bindView(view, context, cursor);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried with something like?

```
boolean isMarked = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("marked")) == 1;
if (isMarked) {
    imgMark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
    imgMark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but didn't worked :( there is still non-wanted marks. And in different items when reopen the app

Comment: Sorry, but i just realized, why you are calling bindView() on newView method?

Comment: I called this method after seeing it in a custom CursorAdapter tutorial that I found while googling for these problem. But the result is the same even if I remove this line

Comment: Oh, I just retested. Your answer about else part is correct. I just confused this ListView with another alike ListView. My bad, sorry for that and thank you so much!